# Cell from xib does not autoresize

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I am trying to create infinite calendar using swift 3.0 + xib. I have 2 .xib files: JKCalendar (collectionView) and JKCalenderCell(date cell). When I use my JKCalendar class on UIView i get calendar that fits this view size, but my cells are off. What is more I cant set correct number of columns using FlowDelegate.

```
class JKCalendarCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var test: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("JKCalendarCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
        addSubview(view)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

[image: Cell schema]

```
class JKCalendar:   UIView,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.collectionView.frame = self.bounds
        self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
   }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadXib()
    }
    func loadXib(){
        let view = UINib(nibName: "JKCalendar", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0]
        addSubview(view as! UIView)

        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "JKCalendarHeader" , bundle:  nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "JKCalenderHeader")

       self.collectionView.register(JKCalendarCell.self,      forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "JKCalendarCell")
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 42
    }

    public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "JKCalendarCell", for: indexPath) as! JKCalendarCell
        return cell
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = cell as! JKCalendarCell
        let dayNumber  = countDayNumber()
        cell.test.text = "\(dayNumber)"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (collectionView.frame.width / 7.0 )
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

JKCalendar.xib
[image: JKCalendar.xib]
My ViewContoller
[image]

And this is what I get after running.
[image: CalendarPreview]

I want 7 cells/row with label in center. I used red color cells with label on right to show how much they are off